# How to connect low voltage track lighting to line voltage?

Tags: electrical, wiring, low-voltage

I want to connect lo-voltage track lighting to the wiring in an 
existing wall outlet. Can I do that? Is there enough "power" in that wall
outlet circuit to handle the track heads?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. So, you'll be connecting the track lighting's supply transformer to the wall outlet? How much power will the track need? (Make and model would be helpful.)

Answer (score 3):

Connecting low voltage lighting to high voltage supply requires a step-down transformer or power supply unit of some kind.  You cannot connect high voltage directly to low voltage lighting; voltage doesn't magically step down that way; it is illegal because it'll cause a fire.

There should be plenty of power.

Your hookup issue is mostly mechanical.   You might use a "wall wart" transformer/power supply that simply plugs into one of the outlets.  Or you could hard-wire it using surface conduit and a spacer that extends the outlet so you make your connection underneath it.